# Laravel Auth::attempt() fails

Tags: laravel

When I register a new user and I want to sign him in by using auth attempt it doesn't work while the user is saved to database

```
static function register()
{
    if(self::$validate['message'])
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => self::$values['name'],
            'email' => self::$values['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make(self::$values['password'])
        ]);

        Auth::attempt($user,true);
        Auth::attempt($user->only(['email','password']));

        return result::repsonse(true);
    } else 
        return self::$validate;
}
```

Comment: You cannot login using the password hash.

Comment: make sense i will try

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auth::login() method

```
static function register()
{
    if(self::$validate['message'])
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => self::$values['name'],
            'email' => self::$values['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make(self::$values['password'])
        ]);

        Auth::login($user);

        return result::repsonse(true);
    } else 
        return self::$validate;
}
```